# What is the WiX equivilent of Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData from .NET?

Tags: wix, installation, special-folders

I need to install a file into the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` folder, which differs between XP and Vista. Is there a built in way to reference the correct folder in WiX or will I have to use conditional checks for OS and do it manually?

If I have to do the latter, how do I reference the current windows user's directory in Vista?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use Directory element with Id set to [AppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565(VS.85).aspx):

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
  <Directory Id="MyAppFolder" Name="My">
    <Component Id="MyComponent">
      <File Source="Files\test1.txt" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This will result in test1.txt being installed to C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\My on Windows 7 and to C:\Documents and Settings\*username*\Application Data\My on Windows XP.

MSDN has a [list of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties) that you can use to reference special folders.

Comment: Note that the `Name="AppDataFolder"` attribute can be omitted here. Only the Id attribute is required there. Also, you can omit the component `Guid`; wix will now generate a stable Guid automatically. Finally, you can omit the `Id`, `Name` and `KeyPath` attributes on the `File` element. The `Id` and `Name` will have those values by default based on the `Source`, and the file will automatically be the keypath of the component because the component doesn't contain anything else.

Comment: Unfortunately, you get an _"error LGHT0204 : ICE38: Component MyComponent installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file."_, so you have to add a RegistryValue as the KeyPath of the component. I wish I could get away with just the file.